# Error "paragraph ended before \text@command was complete" when I add \par in argument?

Tags: macros, paragraphs, parameters

I have written a command to put a text in bold and give a line break. It works fine for me in single line text, but if I want to pass it an argument with pair it doesn't work for me.

How could I resolve this error?

This is my EMV:

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\newcommand{\ccesec}[1]{%
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \textbf{#1}%
    %\par
}
\begin{document}
    \ccesec{Cristo se ofreció a su Padre por nuestros pecados \par Toda la vida de Cristo es oblación al Padre}
\end{document}
```

If I delete `\par` the error disappears, but I need one new paragraph in this case. In other cases there will be lines without `\par`.

Comment: use `{\bfseries#1}` rather passing the argument to `\textbf`

Comment: It's fine! Thanks @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: Logically they seem line new lines (`\\ ` rather than new paragraphs?) If my Reading of thetext is correct.

Comment: @You are right, this is a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more naturally a forced line break than a new paragraph I think, so you could mark it up as

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\newcommand{\ccesec}[1]{%
    {\par\raggedright% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \textbf{\ignorespaces#1}%
    \par}%
}
\begin{document}
    \ccesec{
Cristo se ofreció a su Padre por nuestros pecados\\
Toda la vida de Cristo es oblación al Padre}
\end{document}
```

But if you want to use a paragraph, use the declaration form, `\bfseries`

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\newcommand{\ccesec}[1]{%
    {\par\raggedright% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \bfseries\ignorespaces#1%
    \par}
}
\begin{document}
    \ccesec{
Cristo se ofreció a su Padre por nuestros pecados

Toda la vida de Cristo es oblación al Padre}
\end{document}
```